# which server can host iOS push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I cannot host my own server for iOS push notification because the router is limited by Admin.

I want to learn from scratch so I don't want to use Parse or quickblox. Where and how can I know which PHP hosting plan support iOS push notification? Is there any free hosting available?

From Apple, the server need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 2196. I don't think regular hosting plan will list out this information.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41

When I learnt Android push notification, I can easily find a hosting plan with CURL. iOS is a bit demanding.

Comment: u can check these links to your solution http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

Comment: but I cannot allow inbound TCP packets over port 2196. I am behind firewall and looking for free hosting for learning purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port that you really need for sending push notifications is 2195. Even though the TCP packets are both inbound and outbound from your server, the connection is only outbound (you initiate the connection to Apple). Most web host providers won't have an issue with this.

Port 2196 is the feedback service, which you should implement, but it's optional. It's the same way, inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 2196, but you initiate the connection.

When a device registers with your server for push notifications by sending the device token, the device initiates the connection, and you have your choice of how to send the notification to the server. If you send it via HTTP (with NSURLConnection, for instance), any basic web server will do.

I implemented [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) in only a couple hours and it works fine on my shared hosting environment at Dreamhost. You just need a basic LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and a downloaded copy of your APNS certificates. Easy APNS is all open source, so you can see how they're doing it.

Comment: I am happy to hear that no special port is required. I try to implement EASY APNS on free hosting.

Comment: @Mickey, please don't forget to accept the best answer and up vote it if it was useful.

Comment: Sorry that I come back late. dreamhost is not free. I tried site90.com free hosting with easy apns. I got error of "Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'". So I think the problem is related to TCP port

Comment: @Mickey, Dreamhost shared (paid) hosting works. Goodluck finding free hosting that supports this.

Comment: finally I give up on free hosting. I moved my code to XAMPP and everything work fine. You are right that inbound port 2196 is not required. I can host my web server behind router. Only outbound SSL on php is necessary.